# Save state (child views) in a custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, kotlin, view, viewgroup, childviews

I have created a custom ViewGroup for my app written in Kotlin, specifically a FrameLayout, to which I add multiple child views programmatically. The child views are added depending on user interaction, thus not at the initialisation of the parent view. When changing the screen orientation, the FrameLayout is redrawn without the child views. How can I retain the sate of the FrameLayout, so that the child views are redrawn when the screen orientation is changed?

Furthermore, can the FrameLayout somehow retain the state of the child views (e.g. text in an EditText), or does the child view need to manage its state on its own?

Thanks!

Comment: Do your child `View`s that you create dynamically have unique IDs?

Comment: Hi David, yes, when adding the child views, I assign an ID with: view.id = View.generateViewId()

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the issue this way:

1. Define the ID's you'll use later in R.id class using an xml resource file, for example here: res/values/ids.xml

`<resources> <item name="my_edit_text" type="id"/> </resources>`

2. Set the actual id to your view the following way:

   editTextView.id = R.id.my_edit_text